# How to create a named constant in the SystemVerilog generate block?

Tags: constants, system-verilog, generate

I need to transmit a set of values between the SystemVerilog and VHDL code. To do that, I have to flatten the SV structures into the bit vectors, transmit the bit vectors, and rebuild the structures at the VHDL side.
Unfortunately, I have faced a serious problem at the SV side. My "flattener" has the following code:

```
   generate
    for(genvar i=0;i<nlinks;i++)
      for(genvar j=0;j<2;j++)
        begin
        const int base = 2 * i + j;
           assign vf[base] = lct_aligned[i][j].vf;
           assign hs[(8*base+7):8*base] = lct_aligned[i][j].hs;
           assign wg[(7*base+6):7*base] = lct_aligned[i][j].wg;
           assign ql[(4*base+3):4*base] = lct_aligned[i][j].ql;
           assign cp[(4*base+3):4*base] = lct_aligned[i][j].cp;
           assign lr[base] = lct_aligned[i][j].lr;
           assign bc0[base] = lct_aligned[i][j].bc0;
           assign bx0[base] = lct_aligned[i][j].bx0;
           assign ser[base] = lct_aligned[i][j].ser;
           assign cid[(4*base+3):4*base] = lct_aligned[i][j].cid;          
        end 
     endgenerate
```

Unfortunately, it gives "base is not a constant error" in each "assign" line.
When I replace "base" with "(2*i+j)" the code compiles correctly, but is significantly less visible and mantainable.

```
   generate
    for(genvar i=0;i<nlinks;i++)
      for(genvar j=0;j<2;j++)
        begin
           //const int base = 2 * i + j;
           assign vf[(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].vf;
           assign hs[(8*(2*i+j)+7):8*(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].hs;
           assign wg[(7*(2*i+j)+6):7*(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].wg;
           assign ql[(4*(2*i+j)+3):4*(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].ql;
           assign cp[(4*(2*i+j)+3):4*(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].cp;
           assign lr[(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].lr;
           assign bc0[(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].bc0;
           assign bx0[(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].bx0;
           assign ser[(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].ser;
           assign cid[(4*(2*i+j)+3):4*(2*i+j)] = lct_aligned[i][j].cid;        
        end 
     endgenerate
```

Is there any way to define constants for complex expressions in the SystemVerilog generate blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `const` variable is not really a *constant*. It's a variable with a write once at run-time value. A `parameter` or `localparam` is a compile time constant. Simply replace `const` with `parameter`.

Comment: Using "paremeter" leads to a warning "parameter declared inside generate block shall be treated as localparam". Using "localparam" works perfectly without warnings. Thanks!